# Want to send notification from my website using Facebook Connect

Tags: php, facebook

I want to send notification to users who have authorized my app by Facebook Connect. but not be able to send.Here are issues:

**1, When I run this code on my own user id then nothing is appeared, gives no error and no notification.**

**2, When I run this code to other user who authorize on my app, it gives error:**

```
[error] => Array
(     
[message] => (#606) You do not have permission to fetch notifications for this user
[type] => OAuthException
[code] => 606
)
```

**Here is code i am using to send notification:**

```
$url='http://www.thecreativeblink.com/'.base_url().'trees/'.$schoolfirstname[0]."-".$schoolcity;

$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FB_APP_ID."&client_secret=".FB_SECRET."&grant_type=client_credentials";

$response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];

$this->facebook->api("/USER_ID/notifications?access_token=$access_token&href=$url&template=message");
```

Answer (score 0):

> [message] => (#606) You do not have permission to **fetch** notifications for this user

That should have given you a clue already …

You need to make a POST request to *send* notifications.

Comment: how can i make post request?

Comment: By telling the API the method you want to use as second parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/